# Arduino computing error - giving negative values when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, math, arduino

I have this simple Arduino code:

```
#define percentage 60
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int seconds = 682;
  Serial.println(seconds);
  Serial.println((seconds * percentage));//Should be 40920
  Serial.println((seconds * percentage) / 100); //Should be 409
}

void loop() {}
```

When i run it and open the serial monitor, it shows:

> 682
>
> -24616
>
> -246

But it should show this:

> 682
>
> 40920
>
> 409

Why am i getting this computing error? And how can I solve it? thanks in advance

Comment: probably (16-bit) integer overflow

Comment: @appleapple yes, probably. But when I set percentage to 100 it shows correct results

Comment: @LuisCabreraBenito you get `68200`?

Comment: @appleapple yes, And when i divide it i get 682 (correct results). And why would it be an overflow? i am not storing the value in the variable, instead I am just printing it

Comment: Did you try `long seconds` instead of `int`?

Comment: @LuisCabreraBenito it's overflowing because the expression is done in `int` type. Both `seconds` and `percentage` are `int`s and they're not automatically promoted to `long`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an integer overflow. An int on an Arduino is 16 bits which means it has a range of -32,768 to 32,767.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/int/

Answer (score 1):

It is an overflow error. Try using `long long` or something with a larger range. Arduino `int` is equivalent to a `short`, so I would recommend using `long` or `long long`. As Bennji says correctly, the range is from -32768 to 32767, the same a a `short` for normal c++ compilers.

Also you can divide first and then multiply.

Comment: @Sniper, thanks for editing. That is a much better solution than typecasting